# Does Hibernate3.5 support JPA1+EJB3.0 on GlassfishV2?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, ejb-3.0

Can I use newest version of hibernate 3.5 (3.5.0-3.5.2) as JPA1 provider with EJB3.0 on Glassfishv2?

I tried, but hibernate 3.5 required JPA2 spec and obviously this did not work with GFv2.

Thanks,
Anton

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is. As you pointed out, Hibernate Entity Manager 3.5 implements JPA 2.0 interfaces (like `EntityManagerFactory`, `EntityManager`, `PersistenceUnitInfo`) which have new methods. If you want a JPA 1.0 implementation, use Hiberante EM 3.4.0.GA.

To be honest, even if it was possible, I don't get the point. What parts of Hibernate 3.5 would you like to use that you don't get in Hiberante Core 3.3.2.GA and Hibernate Entity Manager 3.4.0.GA?

**Update:** To use Hibernate as JPA 1.0 persistence provider in GlassFish v2, have a look at this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594079/is-it-possible-to-use-hibernate-as-glassfishs-persistence-provider) (check all answers).

Comment: Pascal, thanks for your response. I am more concerned about support of hibernate as JPA1 provider rather than new features of 3.5.

Comment: @Anton I've added a link to a previous answer about Hibernate and GlassFish v2. But I'm not sure to understand what you mean by *support*.

Comment: By support I mean further development,bugfixing of hibernate as JPA1 provider.

Comment: @Anton I see. Officially, Hibernate EM 3.4 is still supported.